# Reading an EBCDIC character from a file in C language

Tags: c, ebcdic

I'm reading an EBCDIC charater from a file and I everytime I try to write it on a file wether in EBCDIC or ASCII format, all it writes is blank. Can anyone help? thanks.

```
int main()                                
{                                         
    FILE *ifp, *ofp;                       
    ifp = fopen("dd:INPUTF", "rb");        
    ofp = fopen("dd:OUTPUTF","w");         
    unsigned char c;                       
    while (!feof(ifp)){                    
        c = fgetc(ifp);                        
        fprintf(ofp,"%c*", c);                 
        /*fprintf(ofp,"%c*", EBCDICtoASCII(c));*/
   }                                        
   fclose(ifp);                           
   fclose(ofp);                           


return(0);                             
}
```

Comment: I got the conversions table on already. I just didnt paste here.

Comment: You called `fgetc(file)` without initializing `file`.

Comment: Not sure if you are doing some homework or learning about programming, but in case you didn't know, the `dd` utility will convert EBCDIC to ASCII if you do `dd if=infile of=outfile conv=EBCDIC`. Maybe you can use that to check your results :-)

Comment: You are not checking for any error conditions. I can only assume you don't care whether your program works.

Comment: @MarkSetchell am I to edit the jcl or the C code? Didn't know that sorry :)

Comment: sorry about that @n.m. That was my previous code. I have placed error conditions on the fgetc already. :)

Comment: It is neither jcl, nor C code. It is a command-line tool present on Unix/Linux/Mac OSX boxes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix) - also available for Windows here http://unxutils.sourceforge.net

Comment: Don't read it as text: read it as binary - open using rb instead of just r.  The problem is that EBCDIC LF != ASCII LF.  When opening a file as text, you don't know what the chosen line terminator is.  It may not be the one your program is using.

Comment: Please edit your question to show actual up to date code.

Comment: Hi @cup can you explain the chosen line terminator? I dont really get it. I tried changing it to rb. So far it only reads letters. Appreciate the help. thanks!

Comment: @MarkSetchell, is there a way that I can integrate that on my program?

Comment: The OS is either ASCII or EBCDIC based so what it chooses as a line terminator depends on which character set it picks.  If you try to read an ASCII file on an EBCDIC machine or vice versa, it will not find the line terminator.

Comment: @cup The data is coming from an IBM Mainframe running z/OS. There are no line terminators there. Line terminators for a text will be added by the file transfer process, and can br cr/lf or lf as appropriate, in ASCII.

Comment: `while (!feof(ifp)){` is poor; you should instead check whether `c == EOF` *after* reading `c`. And `c` should have type `int`.

Answer (score 2):

You have three file handlers and read from one you did not open. I think you should try ipf instead:

```
c = fgetc(ipf);
```

Comment: thanks for that @simson. didnt really notice I had 3 file handlers. lol

Comment: +1: Note to those who come later: this was an accurate comment before the question was revised at 2014-03-28 01:17:14Z.  It is no longer accurate, but has surely improved the code.